# how to know if UITapGestureRecognizer has been add to subview

Tags: ios, xcode, uiscrollview, uitapgesturerecognizer

I adding subviews programmatic. for each subview I'm adding a gesture reconognizer:

```
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
    imageView.frame = CGRectMake((position*1024)+200,0,image.size.width,image.size.height);
    UITapGestureRecognizer *singleFingerTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]
                                               initWithTarget:self action:@selector(singleFingerTap:)];
    singleFingerTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
    [imageView addGestureRecognizer:singleFingerTap];
    [singleFingerTap release];
```

but the tap is not responding how can I verify the gesture has been add it to the subview ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this after your code:

```
NSLog(@"imageView.gestureRecognizers: %@", [imageView.gestureRecognizers description]);
```

If you have properly added gestureRecognizers it will print the description of each to the console.  If not, it will show (NULL) or an empty array in the console.

---

You can also set the gesture recognizer delegate:

```
[singleFingerTap setDelegate:self];
```

Then add the delegate method and set a break point to make sure it is getting called:

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizerShouldBegin:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {
    NSLog(@"gestureRecognizerShouldBegin: called");
    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch {
    NSLog(@"shouldReceiveTouch: called");
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: in case I want to get the properties of the view tap. How can Implement this method: -(void)viewTap:(UIGestureRecognizer *)sender